# Why was libhal removed in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: 13.10, amazon, hal

After installing 13.10, I realized libhal was no longer a

```
sudo apt-get install
```

away... in fact it was no longer anywhere to be found (except in the Raring Repos).
And installing libhal from the raring repos is not the *best* option.  It is the *best* workaround for not having it.

Why was it removed?  Was it an accidental removal, or is it no longer going to be included in the repos, even in the next LTS?

I ask because Amazon (and other services) require it to be installed.

Answer (score 1):

OMG Ubuntu had an article on this just the other day:

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/10/fixing-amazon-prime-streaming-drm-protected-flash-13-10

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Seen to be outdated or replaced by other packages.
Found this package as removed on repository lists:
[saucy packages](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/saucy/universe/base/libhal-dev)